# Specifying refresh interval in webcal URL

Tags: icalendar

Anyone know if there's a way to specify a refresh interval within a webcal:// URL?  Seems that when using them it's defaulting to a week.

Since I cannot rely on the users reliably changing the refresh, is there a way to encode this in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way built-in the RFC standards, the best proof being that there is a draft to extend RFC5545 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178699%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

> #### 5.6.  REFRESH-INTERVAL Property
>
> Property Name:  REFRESH-INTERVAL
> [...]

But as this is only a draft it is most likely not supported by any webcalendar.

Another `x-prop` was defined and is used by Microsof (and possibly others): `X-PUBLISHED-TTL` (see [microsoft msdn calendar](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daboo-icalendar-extensions-05))

> #### 2.1.3.1.1.15 Property: X-PUBLISHED-TTL
>
> Brief Description: Specifies a suggested iCalendar file download frequency for clients and servers with sync capabilities.

however note that this property being custom may be ignored by some of your target calendars

Comment: Unfortunately, if the calendar is hosted on Google, or iCloud -- you cannot modify these.  And, from what I can tell, if you move the ics files and edit to add these, they will no longer update from those services.

Comment: indeed as those properties they are not supported by anyonelse other than MSFT so Gcal and iCloud ...

Comment: Has there been any update on this? I am creating a service to publish a calendar file but the fact that both Google and MS take forever to refresh hinders my progress. Do these properties force the calendars to update?